# javascript regex to get tag attribute value

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using below regex to find the content of `title` tag **in a given string:**

```
alert("<title  >kjkj</title><title>jjjjj</title>".match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1]);
```

Next I want to find the `content` of `meta property="og:title"` :

`<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />` **is a string**

I have no clue how to do that. **I can't use jQuery or create any DOM element. Its pure a string and i have to work on a given string only**

Comment: How about `$("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content')` ?

Comment: @Ankit That'll work when it is available on page, and not only in string

Comment: I would appreciate if you would undo the down-vote on my answer, as I have corrected it with a valid regex that solves your problem.

Comment: why so much -ve votes to this question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, no DOM, here is the regex:

`/content\=\"([A-Za-z0-9 _]*)\"/`

And if for some reason there are other content attributes in the string that you don't want to match you can just be more specific:

`/meta\sproperty\=\"og\:title\"\scontent\=\"([A-Za-z0-9 _]*)\"/`

[This](https://regex101.com/r/tO4jX2/1) is a very helpful site where it is easy to test regexes of different types.

Comment: i have mentioned that `<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />` is just a string

Comment: If you have access to jQuery, which I assume you do if you're using javascript, you can use it to turn the string into an object and then access the `attr` property. But because you don't want to do that, here is a regex that will work.

Comment: if i run this  `alert("<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"The Rock\">".match(/meta\sproperty\=\"og\:title\"\scontent\=\"([A-Za-z0-9 _]*)\"/);` it shows ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Comment: @Manish Put another `)` on the end... `alert("<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"The Rock\">".match(/meta\sproperty\=\"og\:title\"\scontent\=\"([A-Za-z0-9 _]*)\"/)[1]);`

Comment: what i found is that this solution is space sensitive. e.g. put extra space between  `meta         property=` or `content  = ` will not work

Comment: The fix is simple, I think you can probably figure it out, or I can just show you?

Comment: I am not good in regex so if you will do , that will b a pleasure for me

Comment: Use wildcards `*`. Here is a link to example https://regex101.com/r/tO4jX2/3 , you will see that any possible number of spaces is covered. `\s*` means `any number of spaces or none` If you use the link I gave you, and mouse over each part of the regex it will explain it to you. It is a very useful tool for learning regex!

Comment: This time try to do it yourself! I've already shown you `\s*` All you need to do is add another `\s*` Basically, anywhere there COULD be a space (or multiple spaces) put a `\s*` ! Let me know if you get it.

Comment: oh yes done ...can you tell me what is the meaning of `[1]` at the end

Comment: Ok, I'll try to break it down. Inside your regex there is a set of parenthesis `()`. They are wrapped around `([A-Za-z0-9 _]*)` which is the part of the regex that finds "The Rock". In regex, what is inside `()` is called a `capturing group`. When you use match it returns an array that has the whole string found by the regex as the first element, and the part of the string that you "captured" with `()` as the second argument. So without the `[1]` You actually get two results (try it out). If you change `[1]` to `[0]` you will get the whole string.

Comment: @Manish see my last comment and consider that without the `[1]` you will get `[ 'meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"', 'The Rock' ]` ... you should really use console.log(...) instead of alert(...) and use the developer javascript console in your browser. That way you can keep trying things until they work instead of having to look at pop-ups all the time that don't show you the true values of what you're working with.

Comment: is it possible to combine multiple regex and match all in once. e.g `var result = mystring.match(<regex for title><regerx for og:description><regex for og:image>)` now from `result` if i do something like `result[0]` it should get the first regex result `result[1]` should get 2nd and so on

Comment: @Manish I don't think it will work that way. I would do something like create an empty array `var results = []` and then push each separate match to it. `results.push( mystring.match(<regex for title>) )` then the `results` array will have your matches in it accessable by index `results[0]` etc.

Comment: ahh thats kind of workaround right ? ok leave it . One more thing regarding these regex i found that if let say if 1st `og:descript` `content` is empty but 2nd `og:descript` `content` is not empty then i am supposed to get 2nd content but current solution is fetching just 1st one

Comment: how will you get content of `<meta  property=\"og:description\" itemprop=\"description\" content = \" I am working\">` ?

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible, and generally suggested, to get attributes without using regex, I've created one that will attempt to pull all attributes from an html tag string.

```
var string = '<a href="next.html" title="\'Next\' >>" target="_self" onclick="var target=\'_blank\'; window.open(this.href + \"?test=1\", target); return false;">Next ></a>';
var regex = new RegExp('[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*([a-z0-9\\-_]+)[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*=[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*([\'"])((?:\\\\\\2|(?!\\2).)*)\\2', 'ig');
var attributes = {};
while ((match = regex.exec(string))) {
    attributes[match[1]] = match[3];
}
```

Outputs:

```
{
    href: "next.html",
    onclick: "var target='_blank'; window.open(this.href + \"?test=1\", target); return false;",
    target: "_self",
    title: "'Next' >>"
}
```

It works by expecting an equals sign that follows letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens, and is also followed by either a quotation mark or apostrophe. It'll use the match for the apostrophe/quotation mark to determine when the attribute ends, in case the attribute also contains other apostrophe or quotation marks.

<strike>I've tried to account for possible line breaks and spacing, however, I've still found some edge cases where it will have issues where the attribute contains an equals signs.</strike>

**EDIT**

Adjusted the above code to double escape whitespace and lines, as well as fix issues with nested equals signs `=` and escaped quotes `\"` and apostrophes `\'`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get title tag text and meta tag attributes simply using this Jquery.

```
var title = $('title').text();
var meta_property = $('meta').attr('property');
```