# Get Only Link from JSON data in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am getting JSON data in this format.

```
orderData:"<p>Ключ VVV: 6326233</p> <p>Ссылка на скачивание <a title=\"Movie\" 
href=\"https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/The_Angry_Birds_Movie_2?id=O_RbjOHHpIs&hl=en\" 
target=\"_blank\">Movie</a></p> <p>Ссылка на <a title=\"Boss\" 
href=\"https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/The_Boss_Baby?id=Ry9HH3he- 
YQ&hl=en\">лицензию</a></p>"
;
```

From here I need to get only first link alone. This link => https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/The_Angry_Birds_Movie_2?id=O_RbjOHHpIs&hl=en

How to do it ?

Comment: It is just a string, why don't you use regex to pick first href value.

Comment: can you show me ?

Answer (score 1):

Using regex to solve, something of the sort:-

```
var d = {
orderData:'"<p>Ключ VVV: 6326233</p> <p>Ссылка на скачивание <a title=\"Movie\" href=\"https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/The_Angry_Birds_Movie_2?id=O_RbjOHHpIs&hl=en\" target=\"_blank\">Movie</a></p> <p>Ссылка на <a title=\"Boss\" href=\"https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/The_Boss_Baby?id=Ry9HH3he- YQ&hl=en\">лицензию</a></p>"'
}

var string = d.orderData
var regex = new RegExp('[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*([a-z0-9\\-_]+)[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*=[\\s\\r\\t\\n]*([\'"])((?:\\\\\\2|(?!\\2).)*)\\2', 'ig');
var attributes = {};
while ((match = regex.exec(string))) {
    attributes['href'] = match[3]
}
console.log(attributes)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420491/javascript-regex-to-get-tag-attribute-value)

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly like what @tarzen chubgh said, it just a string you can use regex to get the link.

Assume this is your object

```
const x = {
   link: '<img src="https://www.xasd.com.vn/getsomething?ok=1&yes=1" width=100>',
   other: 'this is not  a link'
}
```

Here is an example:

```
 const pattern = 'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'
 const regex = RegExp(pattern)
 for (const props in x) {
   console.log(regex.exec(x[props]))
 }
```

There are many other pattern on the internet to regex link, you can find more then :D